# Change in the position of mass under the influence of an impulse

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I know that $J=m\Delta v$. Since $\Delta v$ is the only variable that contains any information about distance I can isolate it resulting in $\frac{J}{m}=\Delta v$. Generally change in position can be written as $\Delta R=v\Delta t$ and in this case $\Delta v$ should be rewritable as $\Delta \frac{\Delta R}{\Delta t}$ giving me
$\frac{F\Delta t}{m}=\Delta \frac{\Delta R}{\Delta t}$. From here my intuition tells me that I shouls be able to multiply both sides by $\Delta t$, but I don't think would be entirely useful since the $\Delta t$ on the right hand side is stuck behind a second delta, so I feel as if I've backed myself into a corner. Is there some simpler path that I could be taking that I'm missing or is that path that I'm moving along good and going somewhere?

Comment: If you use the concept of derivatives,the "two deltas" mean second derivative and hence you cannot multiply delta t and cancel it with the one on RHS

Comment: @yashasvigrover, in this case it's a differential (no denominator), but impulse is given so it will have to be non-infinitesimal

Comment: That's a good explanation of why that move would be illegal, thank you for that.

Comment: Not clear. Are you trying to find the position **during** the impulse? Or **after**  the impulse? The former depends on the variation of $F(t)$ because impulse is the integral $\int F(t)dt$ which can be the same for different functions $F(t)$.